# Norms of vectors and components of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_l) \in \mathbb{R}^l, y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_l) \in \mathbb{R}^l$ and $\Vert y \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert$. Does that mean $\max_{i \in \{1,2,\dots,l\}} y_i \leq \Vert x \Vert$? The vector space here is $X = \mathbb{R}^l$.

I know that this is true if you have the $l$-2 norm (by the Pythagorean theorem). However, what if I extend this question to the very general case, where $\Vert x \Vert$ is only a norm of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{l}$?

I'm trying to prove the affirmative but I'm stuck. Can I get a hint?

Comment: 1. Is $y=(y_1,\dots, y_l)$ ? 2. Is $X=x$ ? 3. If the answers to 1. and 2. are *yes*, then the answer to your question is *no* because for example $$\lVert\cdot\rVert\overset{\text{Def.}}=\frac{\lVert\cdot\rVert_2}{100}$$ also is a norm.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I updated my question. By $X$, did you mean the ambient vector space? If so, $X = \mathbb{R}^l$.

Comment: No, you wrote $\|X\|$ last time but as I suspected you meant $\| x\|$ . So you can try my norm from above.

Comment: Using your norm, $\Vert y \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \implies \Vert y \Vert_2 \leq \Vert x \Vert_2$. Doesn't the Pythagorean theorem get me the desired result?

Comment: @user1691278 It gets us that $y_1 \leq \|x\|_2$, but not $y_1 \leq \|x\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, consider the norm
$$
\|x\| = \frac 1{10}|x_1| + 10|x_2|
$$
and the vectors $x = (0,1), y = (90,0)$. It is true that $\|y\| \leq \|x\|$, but $y_1 > \|x\|$.

---

On the other hand, if $\|\cdot\|$ is a [symmetric gauge function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2798681/81360), then it is indeed true that
$$
\max_{i} y_i \leq \|y\|_\infty \leq \|y\| \leq \|x\|.
$$

Comment: $y_1 = 9$, but $||x|| = 10$.

Comment: I do see your point. If I change the norm to $\Vert x \Vert = 0.5 \vert x_1 \vert + 2 \vert x_2 \vert$, $x = (0, 4.5), y = (10,0)$ works.

Comment: @user1691278 Sorry, dumb mistake on my part; see the latest edit. Your example works too